# Backbone Event triggers coordinating between different views

Tags: javascript, user-interface, backbone.js

So I have a main view that has a collection of objects inside of it.  The objects are going to be sliding left and right in a carousel.

I have an event that binds on mousedown *inside* of the main view to track how far they roll the mouse during that time.  However, if they roll off of main view element while still holding down the mouse, I still want to be tracking distance and also the moment when the mouseup event is fired.

What would be a good way to integrate a UI logic like this that starts with a local backbone view but has events that trigger off of the element?  I feel there are some traps, especially in terms of future legibility if I were to spread out the functionality over global and local views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to move the mouse event catcher out of the CarouselView. Actually is not so weird.

You can define an ElasticView which `el` is `body`. It contains the CarouselView and its main job is to listen the *mousedown* in the `CarouselView.$el` and also can listen in the *mouseup* in the `document.body`.

It can also comunicate directly with the CarouselView if you add it as a param in the ElasticView constructor. Or the communication can be done by an *EventAggregator* or a common Model or something.